# Shift Reduce Conflicts

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, conflict, shift-reduce

Below the grammar i make.

1. *S' -> sqf*
2. *sqf -> declarations*
3. *declarations -> declaration*
4. *declarations -> declaration declarations*
5. *declaration -> relation*
6. *declaration -> norelation*
7. *relation -> head body*
8. *norelation -> relatts*
9. *norelation -> reldata*
10. *norelation -> relatts reldata*
11. *head -> relname attributes*
12. *body -> reldata*
13. *body -> empty*
14. *relname -> RELKW IDENTIFIER*
15. *attributes -> relatts*
16. *attributes -> empty*
17. *relatts -> attname*
18. *relatts -> attname relatts*
19. *reldata -> DATAKW tuples*
20. *reldata -> DATAKW*
21. *tuples -> tuple*
22. *tuples -> tuple tuples*
23. *attname -> ATTKW IDENTIFIER*
24. *tuple -> VALUE*
25. *empty ->*

The problem is that the grammar is ambiguous because for some rules there are shift/reduce conflicts. Particularly

at the rules below for DATAKW we have shift/reduce conflict

- *relation -> head body*
- *body -> reldata*
- *body -> empty*
- *reldata -> DATAKW tuples*
- *reldata -> DATAKW*
- *empty -> *

at the rules below for DATAKW we have shift/reduce conflict

- *norelation -> relatts*
- *norelation -> relatts reldata*
- *reldata -> DATAKW tuples*
- *reldata -> DATAKW*

at the rules below for ATTKW we have shift/reduce conflict

- *head -> relname attributes*
- *attributes -> relatts*
- *attributes -> empty*
- *relatts -> attname*
- *relatts -> attname relatts*
- *empty -> *
- *attname -> ATTKW IDENTIFIER*

at the rules below for ATTKW we have shift/reduce conflict

- *relatts -> attname*
- *relatts -> attname relatts*
- *relatts -> attname*
- *relatts -> attname relatts*
- *attname -> ATTKW IDENTIFIER*

Can anyone help me to solve that conflicts, please.

Answer (score 0):

A problem is that the grammar cannot determine where one `declaration` ends and the next one begins.

A simple instance of this general problem: `norelation` can be just a  `relatts` which can be a list of `attname`s. So if you have two consecutive `norelation`, that could be two sequences of `attname`s. How can you distinguish two consecutive sequences from one longer sequence? Or three shorter ones? Etc.

There are many other instances of the same issue.

Unless you've transcribed the language incorrectly, this is a problem of language design, and semicolons are a common solution.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.